# Reuse bigquery queryJob as base query to use for further operation

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, google-bigquery

As the title says, I don't know if it is possible to reuse the queryjob obtained by the execution of a query to perform additional SQL operations. Below an example of what I mean

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
myquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
qjob = client.query(myquery)
```

qjob contains the query results. I want to use this result to perform additional filtering, in pseudo code `...`

```py
...
mynewquery = "SELECT c1 FROM <qjob> WHERE C1=1"
qjob2 = client.query(mynewquery)
```

Hope it is clear. This is somehow similar to the construct

```sql
WITH <query name> AS (SELECT ...)
SELECT a FROM <query name> WHERE...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe pandas is the way to go to your inquiry. You can convert a queryjob object into dataframes, once stored into a dataframe you can manipulate it.

See Code Sample:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

sql = """
    SELECT name, SUM(number) as count
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY count DESC
    LIMIT 10
"""

df = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-results-dataframe

Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering to not use pandas to_dataframe.